# Change background image on ipad after rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, layoutsubviews

I show bg of my app using `UIImageView`. To support correct interface rotation i write `layoutSubviews` method. In this metod .frame property changes correctly, but when i try change image of `UIImageView` just like this:

```
view = [self viewWithTag:1002];    
 ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait.png"];
```

nothing changed. Did I do something wrong or is it impossible to change image of `UIImageView` in `layoutSubviews` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    // change background here

    }
```

Comment: I find it to be a smoother transition if you change the image halfway through the rotation instead of before or after. `- (void)willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {`

Comment: @zekel this method is deprecated by iOS 5, instead you should use: willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

Answer (score 1):

You manage the rotation of your views by using a *UIViewController* (be sure to check out the docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you implemented a *UIViewController* for your *UIImageView* you could set the image in the `viewDidLoad:` method.

You shouldn't override the `layoutSubviews:` method to perform this action. `layoutSubviews:`is to do what it says in the name - it should perform the positioning and sizing of any subiews that this view currently has. You shouldn't need to override this method unless you wanted to do some special custom laying out of the subviews and is called in the run loop when the *UIView* is set to "requires resizing".

I strongly suggest you set your image from from some other location in the code. If you want the image to change when the view is rotated, you could set the image in the `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` method of a *UIViewController* subclass.